# How to load all XML files from sub folders using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, directory

Currently I am using a Excel VBA code to import specific nodes from a XML file into an Excel Spreadsheet. The files are stored by days into separate folders. Once the job is done, usually after 20+ days, I have all the files from the sub folders using the VBA code below:

```vb
Private Sub Create_Heading()
    ' This subroutine creates the necessary headings in the specified cells.

    Range("A1").Value = "Bead No."
    Range("B1").Value = "Duration (s)"
    Range("C1").Value = "Log #"
    Range("D1").Value = "Sched. ID"
    Range("E1").Value = "System ID"

    Range("A1:E1").WrapText = True
    Range("A1:A2").Merge
    Range("B1:B2").Merge
    Range("C1:C2").Merge
    Range("D1:D2").Merge
    Range("E1:E2").Merge


    Range("F2").Value = "Peak Current"
    Range("G2").Value = "Back Current"
    Range("H2").Value = "Peak Voltage"
    Range("I2").Value = "Back Voltage"
    Range("J2").Value = "Peak Travel Speed"
    Range("K2").Value = "Back Travel Speed"
    Range("L2").Value = "Peak Wire Speed"
    Range("M2").Value = "Back Wire Speed"

    Range("F1:M1").Merge
    Range("F1").Value = "Set"

    Range("N2").Value = "Peak Current"
    Range("O2").Value = "Back Current"
    Range("P2").Value = "Peak Voltage"
    Range("Q2").Value = "Back Voltage"
    Range("R2").Value = "Peak Travel Speed"
    Range("S2").Value = "Back Travel Speed"
    Range("T2").Value = "Peak Wire Speed"
    Range("U2").Value = "Back Wire Speed"

    Range("N1:U1").Merge
    Range("N1").Value = "Actual"

    Range("V2").Value = "Date (DD/MM/YY)"
    Range("W2").Value = "Start (hh:mm:ss)"
    Range("X2").Value = "End (hh:mm:ss)"
    Range("Y2").Value = "Duration (hh:mm:ss)"
    Range("Z2").Value = "Waiting Time (hh:mm:ss)"

    Range("V1:Z1").Merge
    Range("V1").Value = "Timeline"


    Range("A1:Z2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A1:Z2").VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    Range("A1:Z2").Font.Bold = True

    Range("A1").ColumnWidth = 5
    Range("B1:E1").ColumnWidth = 8
    Range("F1:U1").ColumnWidth = 9
    Range("V1:Z1").ColumnWidth = 14

    Range("F2:Z2").WrapText = True

    ActiveSheet.Columns("V").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("W").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("X").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("Y").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
    ActiveSheet.Columns("Z").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

End Sub


Sub XMLProcessing_rev0()
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim Address As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Application.StatusBar = "Initializing..."

    ' Check if heading area is empty, if so create headings.
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1:Z2")) = 0 Then
        Create_Heading
    End If

    ' Prompt user to enter the file location
    Address = InputBox("Enter folder location of data files:", "Welding Parameter XML Processing") & "\"
    ' Macro will look for files that satisfy the path: "UserAddress\LOG*"  i.e. LOG____.xml files
    StrFile = dir(Address & "LOG*")

    i = 0
    ' This loop runs for every file in the folder
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Application.StatusBar = "Copying row " & i + 1 & "."

        ' Load the XML document
        xmlDoc.Load (Address & StrFile)

        ' Set values in worksheet to data found in XML

        Cells(3 + i, 1).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log").getAttribute("weld")
        Cells(3 + i, 2).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/totaltime").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 3).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log").getAttribute("number")
        Cells(3 + i, 4).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//sched").getAttribute("id")
        Cells(3 + i, 5).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log").getAttribute("sn")

        Cells(3 + i, 6).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/priamp").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 7).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/bkgamp").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 8).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/privolt").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 9).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/bkgvolt").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 10).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/pritrav").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 11).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/bkgtrav").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 12).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/priwire").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 13).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//seg/bkgwire").Text

        Cells(3 + i, 14).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/priamp").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 15).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/bkgamp").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 16).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/privolt").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 17).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/bkgvolt").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 18).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/pritrav").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 19).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/bkgtrav").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 20).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/priwire").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 21).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//data/avg/bkgwire").Text

        Cells(3 + i, 22).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log/time/day").Text & "/" & xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log/time/mo").Text & "/" & xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log/time/yr").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 23).Value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log/time/hr").Text & ":" & xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log/time/min").Text & ":" & xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//log/time/sec").Text
        Cells(3 + i, 24).Value = Cells(3 + i, 23).Value + (Cells(3 + i, 2).Value / 86400)
        Cells(3 + i, 25).Value = Cells(3 + i, 24).Value - Cells(3 + i, 23).Value


        ' Center all cells in the row b/c formatting is nice
        Range(Cells(3 + i, 1), Cells(3 + i, 26)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

        ' Don't remember what this is for, but it probably resets the StrFile _
        variable to what it was before the loop
        StrFile = dir
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Reset status bar
    Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Because everyday the logs start with sequential names, i.e. LOG0001, LOG0002, LOG0003, etc. I can not just copy all files into one folder and then run the macro. I would like to modify the code below in a way that if I specific only the main folder "root", I would be able to load the files from the sub folders.

I would appreciate any help you could give to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Your code gets the fist file in the main folder with

    StrFile = dir(Address & "LOG*")


  and then loops through, filling the variable with the next filename using

   StrFile = dir()
```

(If you use dir without an argument it returns the next file in the pattern you last used.)

What you need to do is to create an outer loop to search for subdirectories and then for each subdirectory modify your address variable and rerun your code. So

```
    Dim subdir as string

    subdir = Dir(address,vbDirectory)
    do until len(subdir)=0
        StrFile = Dir(Address & "\" & subdir & "\LOG*")

        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0  
                'your existing code here

         StrFile = Dir()
        Loop
         SubDir = Dir()
     loop
```

Comment: Dear @harassed-dad, I have modified the code as advise by you, however I am getting a "Run-time error '5'". Please the modified code in the answer below. Would you please verify if I implemented the loop correctly? Thank you very much. Emanuel

Comment: You have xmlDoc.Load (Address & StrFile)  but the new code has already added the address into strfile so you just need xmlDoc.Load(strfile)

Comment: Thank you for the support Harassed, I have modified but still getting the same error.